# AngularJS: Passing Promise, yet Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

In my angular app, I have 2 methods `save()` and `saveTriggers()`. `saveTriggers()` updates all records by calling a web service (C#). I want to make sure that a block of code is executed after all records are updated in `saveTriggers()` and control is returned to `save()`. I believe I need to pass something from the `saveTriggers()` to make finally block execute. I tried various things, nothing works. Using .then() also gives the same error. I am not that good at JS. Can you please guide me.

```
           vm.updatedTriggers = []; // IDs are pushed in
           vm.saveTriggers = function () {
                if (vm.updatedTriggers.length === 0) {
                    vm.close();
                } else {
                    vm.saving = true;
                    vm.save()
                        .finally(function () {    // ERROR - Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined
                            console.log("Saved all. Closing...");   // Never REACHES here
                            vm.saving = false;
                            vm.updated = true;
                            $uibModalInstance.close(true);
                    });                            
                }
            };

            vm.save = function () {
                //vm.saving = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.updatedTriggers.length; i++) {
                    var trigger = vm.triggers.find(t => t.id === vm.updatedTriggers[i]);

                    var input = {
                        id: trigger.id,
                        target: trigger.target,
                        targetInfo: vm.targetData,
                        event: trigger.event,
                        eventQuantity: trigger.eventQuantity,
                        eventQuantityExtra: trigger.eventQuantityExtra
                    };

                    rpmService.editDeviceTrigger(input);
                        /*.finally(function () {                                
                            console.log("Updated event");  // Reaches here
                            vm.updated = true;
                            return Promise.resolve(2);                    
                        });*/ // Commenting this also doesn't help
                }
                return Promise.resolve(2);
            };
```

rpmService.editDeviceTrigger(input)

```
       public async Task EditDeviceTrigger(EditDeviceTriggerInput input) {
               // calls other methods with await
               // Doesn't return anything
       }
```

**EDIT: Updated Code:** I got rid of the error, but the output is not is expected series.

```
       vm.saveTriggers = function () {
            vm.saving = true;
                   
            vm.save().then
               (function success() {
                    console.log("Returned Result ");
                    console.log("Saved all. Closing...");  // These lines are executed before the event is upated
                    vm.saving = false;                      
                    $uibModalInstance.close(true);
               });
        };

        vm.save = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            for (var i = 0; i < vm.updatedTriggers.length; i++) {
                var trigger = vm.triggers.find(t => t.id === vm.updatedTriggers[i]);

                var input = {
                    id: trigger.id,
                    ....
                };

                rpmService.editDeviceTrigger(input)
                    .finally(function () {                                
                        console.log("Updated event"); // Successfully updates all events
                        vm.updated = true;
                   });
            }
                                    
            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Returned Result 
 Saved all. Closing...
 Updated event
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
 Updated event
 Returned Result 
 Saved all. Closing...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show me the code of rpmService.editDeviceTrigge

Comment: @KiDooSong, I have code for the editDeviceTrigger(). It's an async method that doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you "Cannot read property 'finally'" is because `vm.save()` is not returning a promise

Comment: @aUXcoder, I tried return Promise.resolve(2); I am unaware of how else to return the Promise. Can you help me show, how to return the Promise in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you dont need $q.defer-related things, but u can do same using it if u want.
Here I guess you just need to collect all your save promises and return new resulting one using $q.all:

```
vm.save = function () {
    const myAwesomePromises = []

    for (var i = 0; i < vm.updatedTriggers.length; i++) {
        ...

        const savePromise = rpmService.editDeviceTrigger(input);
        savePromise.finally(() => console.log('edit device finally'));// <-- not sure u need this
        myAwesomePromises.push(savePromise);
    }
                            
    return $q.all(myAwesomePromises).finally(() => console.log('All edit device finally'));
};
```